# How to make sure text in treemap cell do not overflow?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, treemap

http://bl.ocks.org/mundhradevang/1387786

Something similar like this. But I have lots of data so the text is a LOT. So what is the best way to make sure each individual text wraps nicely inside the treemap cell?

I use https://github.com/iros/underscore.nest underscore.nest to nest my JSON data so it looks like this

```
{"children":[{"name":"Afghanistan",
 "children":[{"name":"Qal eh-ye Now","value":2997},
 {"name":"Mahmud-E Eraqi","value":7407}
```

But when drawing my treemap, the text are all over the place,
[image]

This is my D3 code to append the text :

```
 cells
.append("text")
.attr("x", function (d) {
  return d.x + d.dx / 2;
})
.attr("y", function (d) {
  return d.y + d.dy / 2;
})
.attr("text-anchor", "middle")
.text(function (d) { return d.children ? null : d.name })
```

**Full Dataset:**
https://api.myjson.com/bins/g9p4s

**My Full Code** :

```
 var coordinates = { x: 0, y: 0 };
 var margin = { top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 90, left: 20 }
  var cfg = {
    margin: { top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 90, left: 140 },
    width: 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height: 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    color: d3.scale.category20()
  };

  //Put all of the options into a variable called cfg
  if ('undefined' !== typeof options) {
    for (var i in options) {
      if ('undefined' !== typeof options[i]) { cfg[i] = options[i]; }
    }//for i
  }

  var treemap,
    legendCategories,
    uniqueCategories;
  var half = cfg.height / 2;
  var tool = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////// Create the container SVG and g /////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  //Remove whatever chart with the same id/class was present before
  d3.select(id).select("svg").remove();

  //Initiate the radar chart SVG
  var canvas = d3
    .select(id)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", cfg.width + cfg.margin.left + cfg.margin.right)
    .attr("height", cfg.height + cfg.margin.top + cfg.margin.bottom)
    .attr("id", "canvas");
  var innercanvas = canvas
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "innercanvas")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + cfg.margin.left + "," + cfg.margin.top + ")");

  legendCategories = data.children.map(a => a.name);
  uniqueCategories = legendCategories.filter(onlyUnique);

  var categoryTitle = String(categoryKey);
  categoryTitle = categoryTitle.substring(categoryTitle.indexOf("." + 1));
  categoryScale = cfg.color;
  categoryScale.domain(uniqueCategories);
  verticalLegend = d3.svg
    .legend()
    .labelFormat("none")
    .cellPadding(5)
    .orientation("vertical")
    .units(categoryTitle)
    .cellWidth(20)
    .cellHeight(10)
    .place(coordinates)
    .inputScale(categoryScale)
    .cellStepping(10);


  treemap = d3.layout
    .treemap()
    .round(false)
    .size([cfg.width, cfg.height])
    .padding(.25)
    .sticky(true)
    .nodes(data);

  var cells = innercanvas
    .selectAll(".newcell")
    .data(treemap)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "newcell");

  cells
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .attr("id", "rectangle")
    .attr("width", function (d) {
      return d.dx;
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
      return d.dy;
    })
    .style("fill", function (d) {
      return d.children ? cfg.color(d.name) : null;
    })
    .attr("stroke", "#000000")
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .on("mousemove", function (d) {
      tool.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px")
      tool.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 20 + "px")
      tool.style("display", "inline-block");
      tool.html(d.children ? null : d.name + "<br>" + d.value);
    }).on("mouseout", function (d) {
      tool.style("display", "none");
    });

  cells
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
      return d.x + d.dx / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
      return d.y + d.dy / 2;
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function (d) { return d.children ? null : d.name })



  canvas
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,50)")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("id", "legend")
    .call(verticalLegend);




  function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }
```

Comment: There are a number of problems here -- the main one is that you have a huge amount of text data, a lot of which has to fit into tiny cells. Depending on what version of d3 you are using, you might have the wrong code for figuring out the `x` and `y` attributes, too. Can you edit your question to provide a minimal, complete example of the problem? A link to a .block with the full dataset would also be helpful.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I'm using D3 v3. Maybe I could hide the text if it is too small? I tried this http://bl.ocks.org/ndobie/90ae9f1a5c7f88ad4929 but the text are still overflowing out of the rect. Something like this

Comment: @ialarmedalien Posted my full code and also my full dataset.

Comment: @ialarmedalien Did u managed to solve it? If not so , what other info do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to approach the problem of having a large dataset of strings of varying length that we need to fit into boxes of varying sizes.

One way would be to add a clipping path (`clip-path`) to each rectangle element, but I think that would be over the top for a visualisation like this, so we'll use other means.

First, you could add a title element to each `g`; the default action for most browsers is to show a tooltip on mousing over a title. So:

```
cells
  .append('title')
  .text(function(d){ return d.name });
```

Now let's look at the text elements. Set the `font-family` and `font-size` for the text nodes in your stylesheet or document head so that we are dealing with predictable text sizes.

```
.newcell text {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

I would advise shifting the text down slightly as the current code sets the baseline of the text at the vertical centre of the cell, which is too high. Here I've added an offset of `0.35em`:

```
selection
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function (d) {
    return d.x + d.dx / 2;
  })
  .attr("y", function (d) {
    return d.y + d.dy / 2;
  })
  .attr('dy', '.35em')
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.children ? '' : d.name;
  })
```

We can filter the visibility of the text nodes by altering the opacity (which means we can easily toggle the opacity to show / hide the text), using

```
    cells
    .style('opacity', function(d){
      // some function returning 0 or 1
    });
```

There are various different methods we could use to decide whether to show or hide the text. One would be to have a minimum width and minimum height that the cell must be to show text in it, e.g.

```
  var minHeight = 12,
  minWidth = 20;
  cells
    .style('opacity', function(d){
      if ( d.dx <= minWidth || d.dy <= minHeight ) {
        return 0
      };
      return 1;
    });
```

Another way could be to calculate the approximate width of the word and test that against the box width. I found a table of average character widths for common fonts at https://www.math.utah.edu/~beebe/fonts/afm-widths.html, so we can guess the width of the word by multiplying the word length by the average character width (in points), and multiply that by the font size (in points) and the conversion factor for converting points to pixels

```
  var pt_px = 0.75, // convert font size in pt into pixels
  font_size = 10,   // or whatever it is set to in the stylesheet
  averageLetterWidth = 0.58344; // average character width for Arial

  cells
    .style('opacity', function(d){
      if ( d.name.length * averageLetterWidth * pt_px * font_size >= d.dx ) {
        return 0
      }
      return 1;
    });
```

And yet another method would be to compare the size of the bounding box of the text element to the height and width of the cell:

```
  cells
    .style('opacity', function(d){
      var bbox = this.getBBox();
      if ( d.dx <= bbox.width || d.dy <= bbox.height ) {
        return 0;
      }
      return 1;
    });
```

You may also want to ensure there is some padding between the edge of the text and the box:

```
  var h_pad = 2, // 2 pixels vertical padding
  v_pad = 4; // 4 pixels of horizontal padding (2 px at each side)
  cells
    .style('opacity', function(d){
      var bbox = this.getBBox();
      if ( d.dx <= bbox.width + h_pad || d.dy <= bbox.height + v_pad ) {
        return 0;
      }
      return 1;
    });
```

You can choose whichever of these methods is most appropriate for your use case (or combine them all!). I have put together [a block that demonstrates the different calculations and their effects](https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/8830b6df532daf864487c6e622658038).

Comment: Amazing work brother. Do you know if I could add a header to each parent? Like saying Afghanistan, China representing each big color in the treemap. What would be the best way to approach it ? The examples on the internet all have the zoom feature which I dont want.